# pyttsx - loop makes runAndWait() cut off

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyttsx

I want to write a script which will read a list of words as it prints them to the screen.

```
import pyttsx

engine = pyttsx.init()
words = ["here","are","some","test","words"]

for i in words:
    engine.say(i)
    print i
    engine.runAndWait()
```

However, in running the above, all words other than "here" are cut short. I hear something like "here [pause] ar- so- te- wo-"

If I unindent `engine.runAndWait()`, the words are said after the loop is done. When I do this, they aren't cut off, but, of course, they aren't said at the at the same time they're printed.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to print word, how about using callback, using [`pyttsx.Engine.connect`](http://pyttsx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/engine.html#pyttsx.engine.Engine.connect)?

```
import pyttsx


def cb(name):
    print(name)

engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.connect('started-utterance', cb)
for word in ["here", "are", "some", "test", "words"]:
    engine.say(word, name=word)

engine.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a couple of years too late, but using `engine.startLoop(False)` and `engine.iterate()` following the "external event loop" example in the [docs](https://pyttsx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html) did the job for me.

```
import pyttsx
import time

engine = pyttsx.init()
words = ["here","are","some","test","words"]

engine.startLoop(False)
for i in words:
    engine.say(i)
    engine.iterate()
    print i
    while engine.isBusy(): # wait until finished talking
        time.sleep(0.1)

engine.endLoop()
```